# la cadena no se reconoce como datetime válido. hay una palabra desconocida apartir del índice 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola buen dia: Tengo el siguiente problema, al leer una serie de fechas de un archivo excel en asp.net me arroja ese error, lo extraño es que solo con una fecha en especifico, es decir, yo coloco 10/08/2018 y excel me lo convierte a este formato string 10-ago-18. Al leer esa fecha justamente aqui es donde me arroja ese error.

```
public JsonResult Pedidos(List<string[]> lines) {

     for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count; i++){
           pedido.FechaEnvio = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[i][5]);
}
```

ya he guardado fechas con un formato similar, 17/07/2018 y se convierten a 17-jul-18 y esas fechas si me las guarda. Solo la fecha de arriba no.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con esto?

Comment: Deberías poner algun ejemplo de la entrada que recibes y como la recibes, algunos aquí no tienen idea de donde colocas "10/08/2018", sería buea idea que agregaras un [mcve] a tu pregunta para que podamos reproducir tu problema y darte una solución.

Comment: puedes hacer varias cosas, primero arreglar lo del excel que no te lo cambie de formato, o dos parsear la fecha independientemente del formato

Answer (score 0):

Puedes parsear tu string antes al formato que quieres así:

```
string _fecha =lines[i][5];
string _fechaParsed= _fecha.Replace("-","/")
```

Y por ultimo :

```
  DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact("_fechaParsed", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```